# AngularJS: ng-show adding CSS .ng-hide class too slow or after ng-show function is executed

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, coffeescript

**What I need to do:** I need to display sections of my app depending on other sections and elements being displayed and/or selected. Dependency rules can become complex to define and maintain.

**My current approach:** I'm developing an app that uses ng-show to display certain HTML sections of it. Other sections of the page may depend on that section being displayed or not. To keep things simpler I just make ng-show each section with its own ID as a parameter and then check that its dependencies are satisfied, through checking of active .ng-hide class on the dependency. So, to illustrate things a bit, some sample code:

*HTML:*

```
<div id="SECTION/INIT">stuff</div>    
<div ng-show="sectionDisplay('SECTION/GENERAL')" id="SECTION/GENERAL">more stuff</div>
<div ng-show="sectionDisplay('SECTION/GENERAL2')" id="SECTION/GENERAL2">more stuff</div>
```

*CoffeeScript/JS:*

```
sectionsDependencies =
  "SECTION/GENERAL": "SECTION/INIT" #GENERAL DEPENDS ON INIT (always shown)
  "SECTION/GENERAL2": "SECTION/GENERAL" #GENERAL2 DEPENDS ON GENERAL

sectionDisplay = (id) ->
  dependency = $document[0].getElementById(sectionsDependencies[id])
  classes = dependency.classList
  visible = !(classes.contains("ng-hide-active") || classes.contains("ng-hide-add") || classes.contains("ng-hide"))
  console.log "Visibility", visible, e.id, classes
  return visible
```

**My problem or What I need to fix:** .ng-hide class check seems to be applied in an unreliable way from the dependency check perspective, when sectionDisplay function is being run. Sometimes after I check for its usage on a dependency it works, other times .ng-hide class is just not applied yet, which of course doesn't allow for consistent app behavior. However, class is always applied to the HTML element eventually, it's just that I can't rely on it.

**Any idea why this happens or how to fix it? Ideas, alternative approachs?**

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated, but you should not use `/` in the id attribute

Comment: @Ronnie it is valid in html5..can use almost any character except a space

Comment: really not clear what you are trying to do. Checking classes in the dom is very backwards

Comment: @charlietfl what do you mean by backwards? What I'm trying to do is check the status on another element by inspecing its ng-show state, only way I know that can be done is trough element's classes. The problem is that because of some reason, Angular applies the .ng-hide class to the element at a later time, after I've checked it, therefore I cannot rely on class checking it seems, so I need an alternative approach.

Comment: @charlietfl ok have fun escaping your CSS. That's why I said should not and not cannot

Comment: the hide is being applied based on data in your model. It is backwards because you should be watching the model, not the dom

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. CSS DOM querying wasn't reliable.